# Is it possible to disable tooltips for links?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, internet-explorer-10

I don't have any title or alt tags set on my links so IE10 uses the href content for tooltips when I hover or click and hold a link.  I've been looking around but I can't find any solutions for overriding this functionality.

**Update:**

I've figured a solution for another problem I've had.  When you touched and held, a weird square would pop up.  To fix that I used this line of code.

```
document.addEventListener("MSHoldVisual", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

I'm still trying to find a solution to disable the tooltip for touch actions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to?

Comment: @Brad want what? Use IE10? :)

Comment: I'm working on a touch application.  I don't want users to see any kind of popups when clicking buttons.  Sometimes a user with click and hold a button causing a tooltip with information they can't use show up.

Comment: I have just tested this and see no tooltips for links without a `title=""` set in IE10. Are you referring instead to the link location which appears in the status bar at the bottom?

Comment: @Marcin — Usually when I click and hold on a link, it is because *I want to know where it goes* before I follow it.

Comment: @Alfie - It works if you're using a mouse.  But for touch based it isn't working.  At least not when testing using Windows Touch Simulator.

Comment: Ah right, unfortunately I can't test with that. Have you tried setting a blank title in the `onmouseover`, as suggested in the answer below? A quick inline test: `<a href="test" title="test" onmouseover="this.title='';return false;">test</a>`

Comment: @Alfie - Yeah, I even tried using IE10's Pointer events. No luck.