# prevent windows 8 right click square

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, touch, right-click

I have a website (NOT windows 8 app), and it expects the user to be able to hold down their finger on a certain icon for several seconds if they are using touch. However, this causes the "right click square" to appear in Windows 8. It does not stop the page from working properly, but it is annoying and may confuse the user. Is there any way to prevent the square from coming up? I understand that there probably is some really simple, logical way to do this in IE (as microsoft seemed to make it very touch-friendly), but I am aiming at chrome, firefox, and opera as well, as they support touch events and stuff on windows 8 touchscreen computers. I have already tried cancelling the contextmenu event, that just stops the menu from coming up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE10 has the event `MSHoldVisual` to bring up the square. You can cancel both `MSHoldVisual` and `contextmenu` to stop this behavior.

```
// Disables visual
element.addEventListener("MSHoldVisual", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
// Disables menu
element.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

According to this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557(v=vs.85).aspx#context_menus

Comment: Thank you, but, as I said for the other answer, I want to know if this is possible in other browsers. +1, but no accept.

Comment: yea I wonder that as well, too bad I only have the SurfaceRT and cannot test with other browser...

Comment: since other browsers seem to be completely ignoring this issue, I'll accept this answer. Sorry about late response!

Answer (score 1):

Check out if the update that Marcin has mentioned in the below item works for you. I am posting this as an answer as I am not able to add a comment :)

**Source:** [Disable tooltips for links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790768/is-it-possible-to-disable-tooltips-for-links/17791706#17791706)

**Code:**

```
document.addEventListener("MSHoldVisual", 
                           function(e) { 
                               e.preventDefault(); 
                           }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful, but it only prevents the square if the user is using IE. I need my application to support IE, so this is very helpful, but I will not accept it as I wanted to know how to do this in other browsers as well.

Comment: Did you try preventing the default action associated with `ontouchstart`? I read about this somewhere but not sure if it would solve your case.