# How to remove permanent ToolTip on <a> tags in Edge and Internet Explorer when selecting on touchscreen

Tags: javascript

When using a touchscreen, pressing / pressing holding on href links  tags shows a tooltip box with the site address, I cant figure out how to remove this. Does anyone have an idea about this? it only happens in IE and Edge, chrome and Firefox do not experience this issue

investigated event listeners, but no listeners show an event pointing to this

I would be very happy if someone other than me has experienced this and maybe has a fix, its kinda a showstopper for a POS system.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470062/how-to-disable-native-tooltip-for-links-in-microsoft-edge

Comment: Sorry @DavidG my mistake...

Comment: @DavidG seems like the same issue, sounds like im not the only one...

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery can do the trick, let's mess with the title property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").removeAttr("title");
});
// 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").attr("title", "");
});
```

```js
// Hide tooltip on hover, and restore when hover-off
$(function() {
  $('a').hover(function(e) {
      $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title'));
      $(this).removeAttr('title');
    }, function(e) {
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

Comment: Older IE has no arrow function support

Comment: Also may not support Nodelist.forEach

Comment: Have tried these, and none of them work unfortunately.. :( it seems as if there is some sort of hidden listener in IE / Edge which generates it..

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `title` to empty string ( or perhaps just  space). `title` is used for built in tooltip text

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
   links[i].title = ' ';
}
```